# How to read CSV file from second line onwards

Tags: java

I am writing a small program in JAVA, where I am trying to read records from a CSV file.
My CSV file has a static value in first line and comma separated values from second line onwards. I want to read the file that has employee records and show error if the file does not open or exist.

I know that to read a CSV file we use nextLine() like below-

```
 public static Employee readData(String filename){
    
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String csvFileValue = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] lines = csvFileValue.split(",");

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw e;
        }

Employee.java-

public class Employee {
    private String year;
    ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Employee() {
        year = "2020";
    }

    public Employee(String year, ArrayList<Employee> employeeList) {
        this.year = year;
        this.employeeList = employeeList;
    }
}


CSV file-
2020
John, Smith, 28, 05-08-1992
Kate, Adams, 29, 05-08-1991
```

The issue is that my code will read file from first line onwards but the first line in the file is not a comma separated value. How can I ensure my file to read second line onwards?

Comment: Just consume one nextLine invocation without processing the result? Could be completely outside of the loop, or you could have some isFirstLine Boolean that’s initially true, and is set to false in the loop.

Comment: Just consume the first line before the while loop `if(scanner.hasNextLine()) String ignoreLine = scanner.nextLine();`

Comment: Just read the first line and discard it. Or check if the line contains a comma. If it doesn't then skip it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? ignoreLine should be year? year is something that I am skipping.

Comment: @techie_questie, *please elaborate on that?* - elaborate on what? You have been given a couple of suggestions. I not sure what you don't understand about invoking the `nextLine()` method BEFORE the loop so the first line is skipped? Did you actually try adding the suggested code to your class?

Comment: Yes, I did. I am just little unclear on the part where I can store the skipped line value in year variable and remaining in Arraylist(If you look at my constructor) or do I not need to do that altogether.

Comment: Just passing by to leave a tip: while this get the job done, you may want to use a proper CSV reader library when the CSV file get more complex as you probably don't want to deal with double quotes and escaping yourself.

Comment: @techie_questie, you can do whatever your requirement is. If you need the year for later processing then you would read the value into a variable. If you don't need the data then you just invoke the nextLine() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read first line of file and discard it.

```java
public static Employee readData(String filename) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filename);
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
        if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            // Read first line of file and discard it.
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String csvFileValue = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] lines = csvFileValue.split(",");
        }
    }
}
```

---

2. Check if line contains comma

```java
public static Employee readData(String filename) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filename);
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String csvFileValue = scanner.nextLine();

            // Only handle 'csvFileValue' if it contains a comma.
            if (csvFileValue.contains(",") {
                String[] lines = csvFileValue.split(",");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that above code uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. Second method looks more clear to me. I was not aware that just adding if condition before while can actually skip the first and read it from second when we add while loop. It looked redundant to me. If you look at my EMployee.java class, I have separated year param in my constructor since I do not want to read that. So, do I need  to store the skipped line value (i.e year) in year variable. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I have tried by adding if condition before while loop and storing the value of scanner.nextLine() in year variable.